# Extjs keep grid scroll position after store.save

Tags: gridview, extjs, scroll

I have an action-column in a `grid.Panel` which changes a field value and saves the store data. But the grid scroll position goes back to `top:0` each time `store.save` is called.

sample code:

```
Ext.define('SF.view.Myview.List' , {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    viewConfig: {
        preserveScrollOnRefresh: true,
    },

    store: 'Contents',

    initComponent: function() {


        this.columns = [
            { xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            header: 'Action'
            , width: 60
            , items: [{ // change status button
                icon: 'http://whatisextjs.com/BAHO/icons/cancel.png'
                , handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colindex) {
                    var record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                    record.set('status',6);
                    grid.store.save();

                } 
            },
```

I've tried the `preserveScrollOnRefresh` property without success. This property works fine for paging and toolbar buttons but not for `store.refresh/load` events.

Is it possible to save the data and refresh the row without loosing the scroll position?

Comment: take another variable and assign store data into that before grid

Comment: funny cause that's exactly what that switch is for - a refresh

Comment: @dbrin notice that I wrote "refresh the row", and not the complete grid.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, call save method of the record:

```
var record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
record.set('status',6);
record.save();
```

And data in the grid will be updated also.